# Powershell SQL query result not fitting

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, powershell-2.0

Hi I have constructed a script that works fine except for one thing, sometimes the returned string is so long that it doesnt fit in the powershell console and when I later on send the text to a richtextbox I get all the ....... at the end and not the whole string

```
$username = "myaccount"
$sqlconnection = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection
$sqlconnection.ConnectionString ="server=myserver\sccm;database=sccm;trusted_connection=true;"
$sqlconnection.Open()
sqlcmd = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand
$sqlcmd = $sqlconnection.CreateCommand()
$sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT Info from SCCM.dbo.log WHERE Username = '$username'"
$sqlcmd.Connection = $sqlconnection
$data = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter $sqlcmd
$dataset = New-Object system.data.dataset
$data.Fill($dataset)
$global:result = $dataset.Tables
```

I cannot specify the -Width parameter anywhere so I am lost on how to get the full length of the result?

Comment: Your result is not a string, but a [`DataTableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables.aspx). You probably need to enumerate the records from this collection to get what you want.

Comment: Depends what you want to do with the data, I wasn't sure what you meant by 'richtextbox' here so have posted a solution which should give you a CSV file containing the query results, that you can then use as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than display in powershell, you could save the dataset as a csv file:

```
#Fill the dataset with the SQL response. Using [void] redirects console output to null (don't display)
[void]$data.Fill($dataset)

#Pipe the contents of the dataset. Use Select to select all columns/properties excluding those that were created by the DataSet object (not actual data)  

#Pipe to Export-CSV to create a CSV file, use -notypeinformation flag to skip Object type information from the file (e.g. System.String etc)  

$dataset.Tables[0] | Select *  -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, HasErrors, Table, ItemArray | Export-CSV -notypeinformation -path C:\Somedir\Somefile.csv
```